# JSF converter property

Tags: jsf, properties, converters

I am trying to register different converter instances in the faces-config, using a standard converter class to which different parameters are passed.

The code below registers two DateTimeConverters, the first one for dates including time and the second one for time only. But the pattern property never gets set. Can this be done?

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>dateTimeConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter</converter-class>
    <property>
        <property-name>pattern</property-name>
        <suggested-value>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</suggested-value>
    </property>
</converter>

<converter>
    <converter-id>timeConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter</converter-class>
    <property>
        <property-name>pattern</property-name>
        <suggested-value>HH:mm:ss</suggested-value>
    </property>
</converter>
```

Comment: Indeed not. Edit your question, uncheck the "Community Wiki" checkbox and save. Community Wiki is intented to be used for subjective questions/discussions only. Your question is far from subjective. It's just a technical question/problem.

Comment: True, didn't know what it was. But there is no checkbox in the edit page to disable it :(

Comment: Once checked, community wiki cannot be unchecked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible through `faces-config.xml`. The `<property>` declaration which you're trying is not used during runtime.

If all you want is to control the pattern at *one place*, then best what you can do is to create a custom converter. For this particular purpose it isn't that hard. Just extend `DateTimeConverter` and set the pattern during construction. Here's a basic example:

```
public MyDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter() {
    public MyDateTimeConverter() {
        setPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

You can of course get the pattern from somewhere else, e.g. a properties file or xml file in classpath.

Register this converter as follows:

```
<converter>
    <converter-for-class>java.util.Date</converter-for-class>
    <converter-class>com.example.MyDateTimeConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

That should be it. No need for `f:converter` or `UIOutput#setConverterId()`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But what is the use of these properties in faces-config.xml? (the property tag is part of the xsd).

Comment: @JurgenHannaert, look at the [xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd), it says: _"attribute" and "property" elements are intended to allow component developers to more completely describe their components to tools and users. These elements have no required runtime semantics._

Comment: Indeed, such as for example [ctrl+space] autocomplete tooltips/descriptions.